# Vim motion keys sometimes appear on screen when using tmux

Tags: vim, curses, tmux

When I'm not in insert mode and I'm navigating around my file with the motion keys (hjkl etc), the keys often appear in the buffer (illustrated below). I can observe this effect pretty readily in tmux, but it doesn't seem to happen without. If I run `:!reset` in vim the buffer returns to normal, but it doesn't stay that way for long. I'm not sure why this is happening and google yielded nothing. Halp?

Edit: It seems just a simple `:e` will fix the problem, too.

[image: An illustration of the problem]

Comment: Are those keys actually in the file, or are they just showing on the screen?  Find out by hitting Ctrl+L to force a screen redraw in vi.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're only on the screen. As soon as I can replicate the issue again I'll test Ctrl+L. I restarted tmux and the problem hasn't reappeared yet.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there's a bug in tmux that doesn't turn echoing back off correctly when you change things.

Comment: I don't know enough about tmux to know what you mean when you say "echoing". Do you mean that if I change my config there could be some issues that restarting the server would generally solve?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $TERM` inside and outside `tmux`?

Comment: @jasonwryan In tmux I get `screen-256color`; outside of tmux I get `xterm-256color`. Should they match?

Comment: No: that is correct. 9 times out of 10, these sorts of issues are because of an incorrect $TERM.

Comment: Can you start [tag:vim] with an empty [tag:vimrc] and all plugins deactivated and try if that problem still persists?

Answer (score 1):

I experience the same thing.  A few extra observations:

- it only seems to happen when I hold down a motion key like j or k, causing rapid repeats
- it happens both in and outside of tmux, but much more often in tmux
- it happens much more often since I enabled vim-go's `go_auto_sameids`, which I believe is making a call to an external program (guru) for every cursor movement

This leads me to assume that it's a timing issue in vim that is exacerbated by latency added by things like tmux and/or plugins.

(Using gnome terminal; `$TERM` is `screen-256color` in tmux and `xterm-256color` outside)

Answer (score 0):

I think this was alluded to on the tmux mailing list recently. Try decreasing the value of the `escape-time` parameter in `tmux`, so that `tmux` more quickly sends the escape character to `vim` to return to command mode, rather than waiting for more characters in an escape sequence. The default value is 500ms, so try something smaller, like 50.

In `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g escape-time 50
```

Comment: I might be misreading your question; I observe something similar when quickly issuing commands after returning to command mode.

Comment: I'll check to see if this helps, although it seems like this might be addressing a different issue. To get the screenshot I posted above, I stayed in vim (didn't have to enter/exit tmux command mode).